# Does description method matter in Rice’s theorem?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, rice-theorem, decidability

If $\mathcal{p}$ is a nontrivial property of formal languages, then
$L_{\mathcal{p}} = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \in \mathcal{p} \}$ is undecidable by Rice’s theorem.

What if we describe languages with another method instead of Turing Machines? For example, if we define $L’_{\mathcal{p}} = \bigl\{ \langle \phi \rangle | \{ x \mid \phi(x) \} \in \mathcal{p} \bigr\}$, is $L’_{\mathcal{p}}$ undecidable as well?

Can’t we choose, for some fixed property, a description that bypasses undecidability? For example, if $p$ is a linear time property, then $L’’_{\mathcal{p}} = \{ \langle D \rangle \mid D \text{ is a DFA } \}$ is decidable easily by checking that $\langle D \rangle$ is a proper encoding of a DFA.

Does Rice's theorem really depend on the method of description that we choose?

Comment: Well, it is more dependent on the *interpretation* of what "property" is. In Rice's case, a "property" is understood as a "property of languages", rather that some other ambiguous (and less interesting) notion. In your case of $L_p'$, this is close enough to the usual description in Rice's theorem, so we can actually "reduce" between the descriptions. Given a description of *your* $p$, try to describe an equivalent-meaning $p$ in Rice's description. You can also do the opposite, so the two notions are totally equivalent up to the inconvenience of expressing what a nontrivial property is.

Comment: @nirshahar Thanks , How about $L’’_p$ ? Having a DFA is not a property of language ? I want to know the problem of $L’’_p$ that violate Rice’s theorem.

Comment: $L_p'$ is not necessarily undecidable. It depends on what the $\phi$s are. For example if the property is $p$ is *a language is empty* and you just use DFAs as description for your languages; then $L'_p$ is clearly decidable. Rice's theorem only applies if your method of describing languages is [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). So Rice's Theorem does not apply to $L''_p$ because the method of description (DFAs ) are not Turing-complete (because DFAs cannot simulate TMs).